# Have I missed a lot before GA4? It worked ok a few days ago

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

My current setup, which worked ok for years, sends events as

```js
ga("send", "event",
        eventCategory: category,
        eventAction: action,
        eventLabel: label,
        eventValue: value,
        useBeacon: true,
        nonInteraction: true)
```

I go into analytics and it says use

```js
gtag('event', '<event_name>', {
  <event_parameters>
})
```

I'm reading docs for an hour and can't understand what's going on. How to I migrate my existing events to that `gtag`?